# Does Visual Studio 2012 Support XAML 2009?

Tags: xaml, visual-studio-2012

I know 2010 didn't, but does 2012?

UserControls and Windows still seem to be auto-created with 2006 namespaces...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just gave this a try but it looks to me like the XAML 2009 situation remains unchanged in VS2012.

In addition, the MSDN doc for XAML 2009 is identical for both .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5.